# Evaluate the integral $\int_{\gamma} \frac{z^2+1}{(z+1)(z+4)}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

> Evaluate the integral $$\int_{\gamma} \frac{z^2+1}{(z+1)(z+4)}dz$$ if
> $\gamma = \beta + [4 \pi ,0]$ and $\beta(t) = te^{it}$ for $0 \le t \le 4 \pi$.

**My attempt**

By Cauchy's integral formula.

\begin{align} 
\int_{\gamma} \frac{z^2+1}{(z+1)(z+4)}dz &= -\frac{1}{3} \int_{\gamma} \frac{z^2+1}{(z+4)}dz + \frac{1}{3} \int_{\gamma} \frac{z^2+1}{(z+1)}dz \\
&= -\frac{1}{3} (2\pi i)f(-4) + \frac{1}{3} (2\pi i)f(-1) \\
&= -10\pi i \end{align}

I'm not sure whether this is the correct method. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @geetha290krm It is $\gamma$ that is closed, not $\beta$, which runs from $0$ at $t=0$ to $4\pi$ at $t=4\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(z)\to \frac{z^2+1}{(z+1)(z+4)}$

Then $$I_1=2\pi i\cdot \text{Res}_{-1}(f(z))=\frac{4}{3}\pi i$$
and $$I_2=2\pi i\cdot \text{Res}_{-4}(f(z))=-\frac{34}{3}\pi i$$

The total integral then is
$$2I_1+I_2=-\frac{26}{3}\pi i$$

because the pole $z=-1$ is circled twice by $\gamma$ .